# как убрать подчеркивание input

Tags: css3, html5, safari

вот стили инпутов

```
.data{
   background-color: #0e0e0e;
   color: white;
   border:none!important;
    margin: 10px 0;
   height: 30px;
   font-size: 20px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #515151!important;
  outline: none;
   padding: 10px 15px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   user-select: none;
}
data:focus,
data:active,
data:hover,
data:focus {
    -webkit-outline: none;
    outline: none;
   background-color: #0e0e0e;
}
```

как в Safari убрать рамку у инпутов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: border-bottom: 1px solid #515151!important;

Comment: пробовал и не помогает, мне нужно оставить нижнее подчеркивание а остальную часть рамки убрать, но она остается

Comment: Попробуйте добавить свойство `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` и указать для него прозрачный цвет.

Comment: не помогает, написал border-color: #515151;   border-bottom-width: 2px;   border-style: solid; и рамка просто исчезла

Answer (score 0):

```
.data {
   your code...
   ...
   ...
   outline: none;
   border: none;
          }
```

Должно помочь

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]